# Updating a nested object in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below mapping for an index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "xxxxx": {
      "properties": {
        "ID": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "pairs": {
          "type": "nested"
        },
        "xxxxx": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `pairs` field is an array of objects with the below structure

```
{
    "id": "",
    "Answer": "",
    "Question": []
}
```

What i'm trying to do is retrieve a particular nested object and update it. I've tried the `updateByQuery` method with both partial doc/ script but i'm unable to update

**script**

```
var theScript = {
    "inline": "ctx._source.Answer = 'Elastic search update Test'"
}

client.updateByQuery({
    index: 'sample',
    _source: false,
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "ID": '2rXdCf5OM9g1ebPNFdZNqW'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "pairs",
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "pairs.id": "c1vNGnnQLuk"
                                }
                            },
                            "inner_hits": {}
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "script": theScript
    }
},function(err, body){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('body: ', body)
    console.log('data: ', body.hits.hits)
})
```

**partial doc**

```
client.updateByQuery({
    index: 'sample',
    _source: false,
    body: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "ID": '2rXdCf5OM9g1ebPNFdZNqW'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "pairs",
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "pairs.id": "c1vNGnnQLuk"
                                }
                            },
                            "inner_hits": {}
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
       "doc": {
        "Answer": 'Elastic search update Test'
       }
    }
},function(err, body){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('body: ', body)
    console.log('data: ', body.hits.hits)
})
```

I'm getting the below error:

**partial update**

```
Error: [parsing_exception] Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [doc]., with { line=1 & col=191 }
```

**script**

```
Error: [illegal_argument_exception] [sample][conversation][AWa-p9zBTJHq-_gvo-Af] didn't store _source
```

**NOTE** I would ideally like to use a partial doc update for this because the nested object is a bit complex and it wouldnt be possible to write an inline script

Elasticsearch version - 5.6

**UPDATE**

doing something like this works

```
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.pairs= params.pairs",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "pairs" : [{...}, {...}, ...]
        }
    }
}
```

but this essentially means that everytime i update , i'm rewriting the entire `pairs` field (even though i only update one object in array) - this doesnt look ideal to me or is it fine?

Comment: Not an answer, but I've found elasticsearch to handle nested objects poorly -- especially lists and especially when combined with the rest of the ecosystem like Kibana. Everything works more smoothly when you have more smaller flatter documents to convey the same information.

Answer (score 8):

There is a page with a quick tutorial about nested type management: [How to manage nested objects in Elasticsearch documents](https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/02/add-update-delete-elasticsearch-nested-objects) . It explains how to add, remove and edit nested objects.

Comment: An addition I'd make to this: If the script didn't update anything (because the nested object to be updated couldn't be found, for example), then setting `ctx.op = \"none\"` works wonderfully at making the result _not_ be `updated`:

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax for updating a particular nested document. You can only specify a nested field value, and it updates all nested documents. ES reindexes documents anyway with a partial update.

You can use parent-child documents to achieve that at some cost. If your have so many nested records then it may better fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

here's something which might help. Attaching a sample query

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.nested_field.forEach(item -> item.nested_field2 = params.new_value)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "new_value": 100
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

my mapping was this

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "field2": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "nested_field": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "nested_field1": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "nested_field2": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                     "nested_field3": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps :)